# Updating Systemdate for Modified date field asp.net

Tags: vb.net, updatedate

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with vb.net. I am trying to add modified date field into table when the user makes changes to the form in the EditItemTemplate. When I click on the "Edit" button I do see today's date in the field; however when I click on "Update" this date is not being entered into the table. The other fields get edited and saved, it is just the system date field.

`UpdateCommand` has

```
... SET [ModifiedOn] = @ModifiedOn, [ModifiedNotes] = @ModifiedNotes 
WHERE [PatronID] = PatronID
```

Update Parameter tag says

```
<asp:Parameter Name="ModifiedOn" DbType="Date" />
```

This is what I am saying for the textfield.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="strModifiedDate" BackColor="Silver" 
     CssClass="padLR" Text='<%# DateTime.Now.ToString("d")%>' ReadOnly="true" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this can solve the issue to update the DB.

```
   Dim myCommand As SqlCommand
'parametrized update sql command
     sqlconn.Open()
    myCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Table_Name SET ModifiedOn= @ModifiedOn", sqlconn)
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@ModifiedOn", strModifiedDate.Text)
```

Comment: I am using SQLDataSource so where can I add this code? Should I add onclick event to EditTemplate Update button?

Comment: I do not get the option of "SqlCommand" when I try to declare in VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. I modified the "UpdateCommand" to say

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Table] SET [ModifiedOn]=GetDate(),.............."
```